# Android Step 1 from Root Developer Page Activity not Working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-2.2-froyo

I attempted to run "Clean Code" according to [this link,](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) however nothing is happening. From being a Renegade developer my intuition says "Button onClick" is missing but I could be wrong. Here is my code written according to what the instructions are:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class BuildingaSimpleUserInterfaceApi8Activity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.developer.android.com_training_basics_firstapp_building_ui.DISPLAYMESSAGEACTIVITY";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    /**This is how I work with Buttons and the Next Activity, however this method IS NOT defind
     * in the very first Android Tutorial for sending information onClick.
            Button bButtonone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
            bButtonone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.developer.android.com_training_basics_firstapp_building_ui.DISPLAYMESSAGEACTIVITY"));
                    }
                });
        }
       */   

    /** Called when the user selects the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.developer.android.com_training_basics_firstapp_building_ui"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".BuildingaSimpleUserInterfaceApi8Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.developer.android.com_training_basics_firstapp_building_ui.DisplayMessageActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Make sure you updated your layout to include `android:onClick="sendMessage"`, as is described in the "Respond to the Send Button" section on the page you referenced.

Comment: Here is my layout ... I have subtracted nothing from the instructions (but add a menu - exit function as seen in the code)<EditText 
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/button_send"
     android:onClick="sendMessage" />
 </LinearLayout>

Comment: And as a Note over the course of the past 2 to 3 years I have created and published all of these app http://appgravity.com/android-apps;jsessionid=C7FF5AF35C74576D32DA84FA4E1A8772?pub=KaSiris

Comment: @KaSiris how those apps are relevant?

Comment: It just goes to show that I am not a beginner in development ... I wouldn't want anyone to think I just started yesterday, while at the sametime if someone has this very 1 project working according to its instructions I would like to see how so I can start using "CLEAN CODE ACCORDING TO THE DEVELOPER WEBSITE" as potential Employers keep requesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot the line to start the activity:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    ...
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent); // add me!
}
```

Comment: Thank You Sam ... your answer was infact the correct and the process works. I am officially on my way to Building "CLEAN CODE" because of you.

Answer (score 1):

I read through the code at the site listed and you have missed one line:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

at the end od sendMessage.

Comment: Your answer is also correct but Sam was a little quicker with send button.